# Custom id in Sphinx documentation generator

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, documentation-generation

How to create a custom Id for headlines in Sphinx (Jinja)?

Sphinx defines Id same with the headline text by default, but I want to define a different Id

If you write this in text file :

```
Headline text
=============
```

After converting it to HTML file by Sphinx, it looks like this:

```
<span id="headline-text"></span><h2>Headline text<a class="headerlink" href="#headline-text" title="Permalink to this headline">¶</a></h2>
```

But I don't want this Id and I want to define my own custom Id for this tag

If text isn't English, the default value is 's-id{number}', which number sets by Sphinx.

Now I want to write something in another language and I'm looking for a way to change it.

After many searches, I came up with a way like the following, but the problem is that when I look at the HTML source, I see that it still has its own ID next to mine like following:

```
.. _my-custom-id:

مثال سرتیتر
============
```

And after converting to HTML:

```
<span id="s-id1"></span><span id="my-custom-id"></span><span id="id1"></span><h1>مثال سرتیتر<a class="headerlink" href="#my-custom-id" title="Permalink to this headline">¶</a></h1>
```

As you can see, this method still doesn't work and Sphinx still defines its default ID.

What is the solution?

Comment: It has both the default and your custom one. See the second `span`: `<span id="my-custom-id"></span>`.

Comment: But it has crowded the template and is writing extra lines.